# Android Change branded launch background colors when theme is dark

Tags: android, android-theme, android-night-mode

I've implemented dark theme in my application. Everything works fine, when system is on dark mode the application is on dark mode and vice versa.

The problem is Branded Launch.I have 2 drawable files for it:

Dark:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@color/splashColorDark"/>

    <item>

        <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/logo_branded"
                android:mipMap="true"
                android:gravity="center"/>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And light:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

        <item android:drawable="@color/splashColorLight"/>

        <item>

            <bitmap
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_branded"
                    android:mipMap="true"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

In order to use branded launch I added this:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BrandedLaunchLight"
```

in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

Doing this obviously I'm not able to set dark branded launch when dark mode is active. What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a **`DayNight`** theme (`Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` or `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight`) in your app.
Then use the [**`-night` qualifier**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#NightQualifier) on your resource folders as `drawable-night` and `values-night`.

It means use the same name for your drawable in the branded launch for dark and light theme but use the
`drawable-night` and `drawable` folder.
You can do the same for the colors. Instead of using `@color/splashColorDark` and `@color/splashColorLight` use a single name `splashColor` and put it in the `values-night\colors.xml` and `values\colors.xml`

**Note**. Check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#launch_screens):

> *Launch screens*
>
> If your app has a custom launch screen, it may need to be modified so that it reflects the selected theme.
>
> Remove any hardcoded colors, for example any background colors pointing may be white. Use the **`?android:attr/colorBackground` theme attribute instead**.
>
> Note that **dark-themed** `android:windowBackground` drawables **only work on Android Q**.